# Array manipulation (compare) by specific algortihm

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 array and i need compare these arrays by my specific algorithm.

Firstly, my arrays:

```
$old = [
    'pencil' => 'red',
    'eraser' => 'green',
    'bag'    => 'blue'
];

$new = [
    'pencil'   => '',
    'eraser'   => '',
    'computer' => 'mac',
    'bag'      => '',
    'activity' => [
        'jumping',
        'pool',
        'reading'
    ]
];
```

Then, I wanna get this output:

```
$output = [
    'pencil'   => 'red', // old value
    'eraser'   => 'green', // old value
    'bag'      => 'blue', // old value
    'computer' => 'mac', // new key & values
    'activity' => [ // new key & values
        'jumping',
        'pool',
        'reading'
    ]
];
```

So, elements (array item) in both old and new arrays will be added to the output but values should come from the old array.

The elements (array item) in the new array should be transferred to output exactly.

I wanna support my question with a photo attachment ( the sequence on the photo may not match the sequence on the my arrays ($old, $new) ):

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GSe7.jpg)

Comment: It looks like you just want to overlay `$old` on top of `$new`, there's nothing very specific about it unless I'm missing something. I think `array_replace_recursive` should do the job. See https://eval.in/892702

Comment: I'll try `array_replace_recursive()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following code can achieve what you are looking for:

```
$output = []
foreach($old as $key => $value){ 
  $output[$key] = $value;
}

foreach($new as $key => $value){
  if(!array_key_exists($key, $output)){
    $output[$key] = $value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) in order to merge element of two array:

```
$result = array_merge($new, $old);
```

The values from the second array ($old) will be merged on the first array so if you have a key in both array, the second one will be presented in the result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution,

```
$old = [
    'pencil' => 'red',
    'eraser' => 'green',
    'bag'    => 'blue'
];

$new = [
    'pencil'   => '',
    'eraser'   => '',
    'computer' => 'mac',
    'bag'      => '',
    'activity' => [
        'jumping',
        'pool',
        'reading'
    ]
];

$output = [];

foreach ($new as $newkey => $newvalue) {
    if($newvalue!=""){
        $output = [$old+$new];
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($output);
echo "</pre>";
exit;
```

Here output look like,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [pencil] => red
            [eraser] => green
            [bag] => blue
            [computer] => mac
            [activity] => Array
                (
                    [0] => jumping
                    [1] => pool
                    [2] => reading
                )

        )

)
```